# Why do I need a DataHandler?

Tags: java, web-services, apache, jakarta-ee, network-programming

What is the main reason of using a `javax.activation.DataHandler`?

Is it to facilitate the transfer of objects, that do not implement Serializable, over the network?

I.e. for instance I have seen the conversion of files, from local file systems, to bytes and then create a `DataHandler` with these bytes and transfer the `DataHandler` over the network.
Is this the reason that one would use `DataHandler`?

Comment: You have a lot of questions going on there. Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Lord:I updated my question.Is this more specific or extra editing is needed?

Comment: @Martin: If you already go around editing titles, please make it really better, not only change capitalization. "Question on ..." is never a good title.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'll lead off with the start of the description from the [API entry for `DataHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/activation/DataHandler.html):

> The DataHandler class provides a consistent interface to data available in many different sources and formats. It manages simple stream to string conversions and related operations using DataContentHandlers.

Admittedly, that's not the clearest description. `DataHandler` has to do with XML and SOAP, which you can see from the [the use tab of its API page](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/activation/class-use/DataHandler.html). Like you, I've used it to represent data about an uploaded file as it's being sent from one web service component to another for processing.

The `Transferable` interface that `DataHandler` implements is not exactly referring to "transfer" of the kind serialization deals with. It's about transfer of information between separate components in a program, or separate programs, not saving an object for later use. See the [API entry for `Transferable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Transferable.html) for more. You'll notice that it links to [the Drag 'n' Drop Java Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html), which has little to do with `DataHandler` but does illustrate a use of `Transferable`.

Answer (score 2):

There are also performance considerations i.e. using a javax.activation.DataHandler for a SOAP attachment will improve performance.

e.g. as mentioned by Oracle "...Improved Performance: Informal tests have shown that using DataHandler wrappers doubles throughput for image/gif MIME types, and multiplies throughput by approximately 1.5 for text/xml or java.awt.Image for image/* types...." this is from [LINK](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19879-01/821-0269/abebo/index.html)

#### Other references

- A discussion of Base64 encoding vs. binary attachment types [MTOM and DataHandler LINK](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/mtom-guide.html)
- Apache CXF on MTOM [LINK](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/mtom-attachments-with-jaxb.html)

Comment: Is there any alternative solution in case of a DataHandlers?